# systemd service fails to start script in home directory

Tags: python, 22.04, systemd, services

I would like to start a python script (i.e. a Flask server) at boot of Ubuntu 22.04. I have created a file `/lib/systemd/system/myService.service` with following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=The service starts a Flask server

[Service]
User=myUsername
ExecStart=/home/myUsername/PycharmProjects/myProject/server/server.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`server.sh` contains the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate huggingface
python server.py
```

When I start the service, I'm getting the following error:

```
Mar 28 02:04:39 myComputer systemd[1]: Started myService.
Mar 28 02:04:39 myComputer  systemd[1713428]: myService.service: Failed to locate executable /home/myUsername/PycharmProjects/myProject/server/server.sh: Permission denied
Mar 28 02:04:39 myComputer  systemd[1713428]: myService.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/myUsername/PycharmProjects/myProject/server/server.sh: Permission denied
Mar 28 02:04:39 myComputer  systemd[1]: myService.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 28 02:04:39 myComputer  systemd[1]: myService.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I directly execute `server.sh` it works, so the problem is the service. I think that the problem could be that I want to start the script in my home directory.

Is there a possibility to get the service to start the server.sh in my home directory? I don't want to move it outside of my home because other users have access to the computer and they should not have access to the files.

Comment: So is the script's execute bit set? When you *"execute server.sh"* do you do so as `./server.sh` or as `bash server.sh` for example? Have you installed/configured `conda` in such a way that it is available outside of your interactive shell session?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I did `chmod +x server.sh`. I'm executing it as `./server.sh`. I removed the conda command from server.sh script and there is still the same error, so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Where does your home directory reside? is it perhaps not mounted at this point (on a remote server for example, or encrypted and not mounted until you log in)?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem
I solved doing `sudo setenforce 0`